# How to remove NaN from Expression

Tags: reporting-services

Why does the following expression give a NaN error:

```
= SUM(SUM(Fields!SF.Value) + (SUM(Fields!DF.Value)*2))/(SUM(Fields!DialTime.Value)/3600)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either (or ALL of) SF.Value, DF.Value, DialTime.Value are NaN i.e. not a number.

You need to either

- Make sure they are all numbers in your dataset OR
- Add IsNothing() around each potential value.

You should also ensure you are not dividing by zero.

Comment: All are numbers, how would you suggest adding IsNothing()?

Comment: IIF(IsNothing(your_value),0,your_value)